# Android CacheResponse: get file path?

Tags: android, httpresponsecache, responsecache

Is there a way to retrieve the file path of an Android `CacheResponse`? Sure, one can get an `InputStream`, but in cases where some API (e.g. NDK code) expects a file path that does not help. Sure one can use this stream to produce another file, but that's more time and space.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this myself.

On Android (tested on Jellybean), the cache file path is the lowercase MD5-sum of the URI followed by

> **.1**

So for the URL **[Android CacheResponse: get file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058109/android-cacheresponse-get-file-path)** the following files exists in the cache-directory.

> - **bf9b8f9a33062f084a70cba99dc79afe.0** - contains the headers of the HTTP response
> - **bf9b8f9a33062f084a70cba99dc79afe.1** - contains the body of the HTTP response

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so pondering this a bit further (and poking at the code), I have to assume that response headers, etc, are in the same file -- not just the response body.  If so, then there would clearly be no file path one could provide that was simply the response body.  Confirmation would be helpful -- as would pointers to alternative HTTP caching libraries that would help here.

Comment: Actually it appears the underlying implementation retains separate metadata and body files -- great!  But I don't see a good way to actually get the body file path.

Comment: Is there still no way to get the local file path?